# Controlling Brightness of tablet with Qt Android

Tags: java, android, c++, qt, brightness

I tried the Qt forums but with no avail. I'm trying to develop an Android application that one of the functionality is changing the brightness of the tablet backlight. I have successfully written two programs in Android Studio (in Java) using the LayoutParams and Android `putInt` system brightness to change brightness. The issue comes when I try to move the code to my Qt application. I have the JNI code working and it runs my functions, but when I paste the brightness code in to change brightness method the application fails.

From what I understand of Android and the error statements, my issue (I think) is I am not running the code on the UI thread. I've tried to force my Java method to be a Runnable and use `runonUiThread` but that doesn't support the `ContentResolver` or Window because it is not an Activity.

Does anyone have experience with this that can guide me? Or have any experience getting anything in the Android settings to work?

I appreciate everyone helping out,
Andrew

Answer (score 2):

You could have it in a static Java method like :

```
package com.MyApp;

public class BrightnessChanger
{
    public static int change(int n)
    {
        float brightness = n / (float)255;
        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
        lp.screenBrightness = brightness;
        getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
    }
}
```

You can then call this static Java function from your C++ code :

```
bool retVal = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticMethod<jint>
                        ("com/MyApp/BrightnessChanger" // class name
                        , "change" // method name
                        , "(I)I" // signature
                        , 50);
```

Here you pass a value between `1` and `255` to the function.